# Kendo UI Chart causes protractor waiting on Angular timeout issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a simple chart definition:

```
<kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let series of chartSeries"
      type="column" 
      field="amount" 
      categoryField="period"  
      [data]="series.dataPoints">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

Any protractor test running on the page with the chart fails with the typical:

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds.
```

Replacing the chart definition with a nested `*ngFor` and spitting out the chart data to HTML allows the tests to run successfully.

Is it possible to run protractor tests with Kendo UI charts? The project is built with angular-cli and using `ng e2e` to run the tests.

Comment: what are the tests for?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Testing other components on the page unrelated to the chart output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears when calling `browser.waitForAngular()` on a page with a Kendo chart.

It can be resolved by adding `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true` to the protractor config.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in the spec.js file for removing this issue:

```
beforeEach(function(){
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; 
});
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of protractor though. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't affect how the protractor tests run and rather solves the issue with the chart.